# VS Code Docker registry view produces invalid-url for custom registry

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code's Extension: (Microsoft) Docker I have added a custom Generic Registry URL (to a Nexus registry).

This registry works with docker pull command line, but VS Code only shows "Invalid URL" when I want to browse it. I suppose it tries to connect and gets an error like permission denied or it misses an API version prefix or such.

Is there a way to see what was requested and what the rejection code was?

Does it work with untrusted https?

[image: Screenshot of Navigation Bar with the Error]

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but meanwhile it works after using the correct login credentials.